# Color descriptor OpenCV

Tags: opencv, colors, feature-extraction

I am using openCV to extract color information for each pixel in an image. I have found openCV has provided that through "OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor", but I have no idea how to use it. Can some one please provide me demo code that extracts color information pixel by pixel in an image? Thank you.

Comment: OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor retrieves 2d feature descriptors(like SIFT or ORB), not color information. i think, you're barking up the wrong tree. are you trying to get the color values for single pixels ? that would make a total different (but much easier) topic.

Comment: Hi, I am looking to get color information to describe pixel.

Answer (score 0):

to access a pixel, use:

```
uchar v = img.at<uchar>(row,col); // grayscale, 1chan, 8bit
Vec3b v = img.at<Vec3b>(row,col); // rgb, 3chan, 3*8bit
// v[0]==b; v[1]==g; v[00]==r;
```